# Node.js ajax call, does a data argument that's too long result in a "404 not found" error?

Tags: ajax, node.js, get

I'm using an ajax request to send in ids and get information from my database to populate a table.  Here's the client side:

```
userLookup: function (callBack, idList) {
    var data;
    data = { 'idList': idList};
    var url = "/idLookup";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        }
    });
}
```

And the server side starts like this:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.get('/idLookup', function (req, res) {
    ....
```

The idList variable is a comma-seperated list of ids.  When there are only 10 or so it works find, but when I get to about 50-100 I get a "404 - File not Found" error.  Anyone know why this is, and how I can fix it?

Comment: IDK if there is a limit to the amount of data you can pass in the GET url; perhaps try using a POST request instead of GET? If that fails too then the problem is most likel your code in the route handling function.

Comment: btw, by convention, asynchronous functions are defined so the callback is the final argument: `function (callBack, idList) {` -> `function(idList, callback)`

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip.  And yeah, I think there is a limit to how much data you can pass into a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there must be a limit on what you can pass into the 'data' parameter in a GET request.  I did this and it works now.

```
userLookup: function (callBack, idList) {
    var data;
    //data = { 'idList': idList};
    var url = "/idLookup?idList=" + idList;
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        //data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            callBack(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Interesting, you'd think that your handcrafted would be identical to whatever jQuery does behind the scenes. glad its workin'